# Palette getDominantColor method , not working correctly in white color image

Tags: java, android, palette

Palette getDominantColor method , not working correctly in white color image, What am I doing wrong.

here are 3 examples,

My code,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RelativeLayout back_layout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        back_layout = findViewById(R.id.back_layout);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.met4);
        Palette palette = Palette.from(bitmap). generate();     
        int Color = getResources().getColor(R.color.color1);        
        int[] x = new int[]{palette.getDominantColor(Color.WHITE), Color};
        GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, x);
        gd.setCornerRadius(0f);
        back_layout.setBackground(gd);
    }
}
```

[image]

Image in spotify:

[image]

Comment: I solved, with this method,  int vibrant = palette.getVibrantColor(0x000000);